# How do I conform Windows folders to a list view with desktop.ini?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, desktop.ini

I'd like to create an `ini` file or maybe a `registry value` - something I can backup and restore and that sets a folder's view to a list grouped by type.

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQXiX.png)

Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just set the default File Explorer view to that configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, I've figured it out. That may solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ramhound I did some searching and found that I can [change one of the Windows templates](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2980339/windows/how-to-customize-windows-file-explorers-details-view.html) to the look I like - (and, optionally, include a desktop.ini file in each folder)